# Record video and audio from a GLSurfaceView and export it to .mp4

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am a newbie in OpenGL.
I want to record video and audio from a GLSurfaceView and export it to .mp4 (or other formats).
I have a `GlsurfaceView` that implement `Renderer`

I've tried using fadden examples's in [bigflake.com](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) like `EncodeAndMuxTest.java` ,or `RecordFBOActivity.java` in [google/grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) but without success because I don't know how to implement it.

Is there any example or "How-to" for recording a GLSurfaceView?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use INDE Media for Mobile: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials GLCapturer class, it allows to make opengl capturing in a few lines of code, samples are here:

https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/org/m4m/samples/GameRenderer.java

```
synchronized (videoCapture) {
    if (videoCapture.beginCaptureFrame()) {
        ...

        renderScene();

        videoCapture.endCaptureFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to play video in render scene instead of creating trianle?

Comment: Hey @marlon, this link are no more active, do you have the copy of the links code in git. if yes can you update the link in this answer, will be helpful for all.

Comment: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/org/m4m/samples/GameRenderer.java

Answer (score 3):

You can give the [Android Breakout patch](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#BreakoutPatch) a try.  It adds game recording to [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).

The main difference when working with GLSurfaceView, rather than SurfaceView, is that GLSurfaceView wants to manage its own EGL context.  This requires you to create a second context that shares data with GLSurfaceView's context.  It's a bit awkward to manage, but is doable.

You may want to consider switching from GLSurfaceView to SurfaceView.  This requires you to do your own EGL setup and thread handling, but you can find examples of both in Grafika.  It's a bit more work to get things set up, but it makes fancy stuff like video recording easier.  Of course, if you're using a game or graphics engine that requires GLSurfaceView, that won't be an option.

Comment: Thanks fadden! I'll give a try and let you know!