# Record the glsurfaceview

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446982/14956188) in the update #2 section is there any way to provide the `Surface` from `glSurfaceview` to the `MediaRecorder`?

Or it has to implement from the `SurfaceView` like in the [RecordableSurfaceView](https://github.com/spaceLenny/recordablesurfaceview) which use `MediaRecorder` and in the [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) which use `MediaCodec`?

Update:

After do some more searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770554/14956188) which may be the answer. By the way as I have said in the title, I only need to record the rendered glSurfaceView so I'm still open to any suggestion that helps me achieve it.

Another good [reference](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/android-opengl-es-preview-record-with-camera-and-add-filter.html)